# Post Pictures to album with Privacy so everyone can see viz Graph

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, privacy

Here is my Code . I need to set the privacy so everyone can see the picture , but it doesnt seem to work , Only friends can see the picture not everyone.

```
<script> 
    var token="<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token'];?>";
            $.post("https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $sqlr['regidfriendsid']; ?>/feed", { 
        access_token: token, 
        picture: "https://mysite/_n.jpg" ,
        link: "https://www.mysite.com/login.php?ref=owall",
        caption: "Check ur Intelligence ",
        privacy: '{value: "EVERYONE"}',
        message: " Click to know your intelligence level? "
    });

    </script> 

`
```

Comment: have you tried with  "Visibility of the album. "  ??  although thr is a NOTE but you may try

Comment: @swapnesh - I used that option only , and I implemented the Code that you just suggested , Still No luck .

Answer (score 0):

You can set privacy seeting :

NETWORKS_FRIENDS

Look at this url :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.createAlbum/

```
<script> 
var token="<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token'];?>";
        $.post("https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $sqlr['regidfriendsid']; ?>/feed", { 
    access_token: token, 
    picture: "https://mysite/_n.jpg" ,
    link: "https://www.mysite.com/login.php?ref=owall",
    caption: "Check ur Intelligence ",
    privacy: '{value: "EVERYONE"}',
    message: " Click to know your intelligence level? "
});

</script>
```

Comment: i guess he is looking for EVERYONE not NETWORKS_FRIENDS

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know then --

```
privacy: {value: "EVERYONE"},
```

instead of --

```
privacy: '{value: "EVERYONE"}',
```

Comment: No , It didnt work 

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) https://graph.facebook.com/ID/feed`

Comment: I've severely tested passing this json object. No success. I guess fb respects the users privacy settings over this. Also, there's nothing in the manuals about using this json object when creating albums